# Oauth2.0 for Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

let me know if we run the php script on the Google cloud is oauth2.0 authentication required? because we are running the script on the Google platform.

I want to query the Big Query Table and get the result displayed on the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to access the BigQuery API, you need to authenticate using OAuth 2.0.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization